# Formatting to_json method for child object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a  Rails object Product:

```
{
    id: 1
    name: 'soup'
}
```

And a Customer object:

```
{
    id: 20
    name: 'Ryans'
}
```

They are linked via:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
```

When I call Product.to_json(methods: [:customer]), I get:

```
{
    id: 1
    name: 'soup',
    customer: {
        id: 20
        name: 'Ryans'
    }
}
```

But I need this to be in the format:

```
{
    id: 1
    name: 'soup',
    customer_name: 'Ryans'
}
```

Is this possible? I'm using Rails v4.1.7

Comment: You can implement the method `customer_name` and then call `to_json(methods: [:customer_name])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delegate `name`to your `Customer` class

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  delegate :name, to: :customer, prefix: true
```

You can then do

```
Product.to_json(methods: [:customer_name])
```